# Textfield getting hidden by keyboard in corona sdk

Tags: android, ios, lua, keyboard, coronasdk

In my project, there is a form for the user to fill the details. In the form I have few text fields, one under the other, and it's passing the height of the keyboard(goes behind the keyboard). The keyboard hides the text fields on bottom of screen. Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution to this would be to put the whole view inside a [scroll view](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/widget/newScrollView.html) and then, inside the text field handler you put do something like this:

```
if event.phase == "began" then
    -- SCROLL VIEW UP
    scrollView:scrollToPosition
    {
        y = some_position,
        time = time,
    }                
elseif event.phase == "ended" then
    -- SCROLL VIEW DOWN    
    scrollView:scrollToPosition
    {
        y = default_position,
        time = time,
    }     
end
```

Comment: How can we implement scroll view in it.??

Comment: Just take a look at the Corona API for a scroll view. Then just use the function scrollView:insert(object) to insert an object inside the scroll view. They have some nice example code on there as well.

Comment: I want to include a text box in my app in which do not need horizontal scrolling. How can i do this in corona?

`local sugg_field = native.newTextBox( 40, 155, 240, 150)

sugg_field.isEditable = true

sugg_field.font = native.newFont("PTSans-Regular", 17)`

Comment: As far as I know this should be default in Corona. Since a text box is used for multi-lined text it should wrap the text according to the width of the box.

Comment: the scrollView problem is not solved yet. I have 3 text fields, 1 button on bottom of page and implemented a scrollView, added all these objects to scroll view, and written a specific actionListener to the bottom textfield and written the code snippet in it. But still the problem is , when i click on the bottom text field the other objects disappears.

Comment: Its really hard to help you out without being able to take a look at your code. Maybe you can paste it on http://pastebin.com and send me the link.

Comment: You are not specifying the time variable in the text listener. Try replace it with e.g. 200.

Comment: Define the scroll height: scrollView:setScrollHeight(_height*2) and then set scrollToPosition as scrollView:scrollToPosition
        {
                y = -_height/4,
                time = 200,
        }

Comment: I don't know about the values but I'm sure you will work that out.